# Replay Mode for Google Map

Tags: dictionary

Is there a "replay" mode for google map? Namely I want to see:
1) markers, 
2) if there are multiple markers, show them in order based on some criteria such as time,
3) if possible control play back speed

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Maps not programming

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of that.  Would'nt be to difficult to roll your own in JavaScript.  You'd iterate through the markers in a loop triggered by a timer (setTimeout() that you control the speed of) and add (or just show) the markers as appropriate.